# how to delete many-to-many relations in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i'm trying to delete my m2m relation, i think i wrote it right, but in the DB nothing happens, and there is nothing happening on the website too

here is my **models.py**

```py
class Department(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    info_grafana = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

and my **views.py**

```py
class ViewUserAccount(View):
    def post(self, request, id_account: int, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.POST.get('_method') == 'delete':
            self.delete(request, id_account)
        else:
            self.create(request, id_account)
        
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))


    def delete(self, request, id_account):

        id_direction = request.POST.get('direction_id')
        id_project = request.POST.get('project_id')

        if id_project:
            project = Project.objects.get(id=id_project)
            project.users.remove(User.objects.get(id=id_account))

        elif id_direction:
            direction = Department.objects.get(id=id_direction)
            direction.users.remove(User.objects.get(id=id_account))
```

the main point that i want to delete user from department/project, but nothing is happening :(

that is what i get from frontend

```json
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Fa3C0uuP4dlsrvSr1zkvD9UiovRnid7JYYRPRSksNsm0cLXCFPs4ROT0k2M7nv2E'], '_method': ['delete'], 'id_project': ['1'], 'id_direction': ['68']}>
```

Comment: What request did you make?

Comment: well, i make get request to see all my users, then if i want to delete the relation, i post request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a typo while trying to get your parameters (frontend is sending `id_project` and `id_direction` but you're trying to get `project_id` and `direction_id`). To solve it just change:

```py
def delete(self, request, id_account):
    id_direction = request.POST.get('id_direction')
    id_project = request.POST.get('id_project')
    ...
```

Comment: ahhhh, i hate myself when i do those stupid mistakes...
Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your problem it would be nice if you mark it as accepted!